# import discord is not recognized in Python,

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I have already installed the discord package with the command: `py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py` , but it doesn't seem to recognize it.

I have manually checked in the install folder for the files and already tried reinstalling the package. I also modified the Path in the this *PC* -> *Properties*.

Comment: Is the interpreter you're using in your IDE the same one as the one in your command-line? Do you have any other discord-related packages installed? (these often break your discord.py installation)

Comment: PYTHONPATH is likely what you are looking for. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PYTHONPATH+windows)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your interpreter in your IDE. If you have multiple versions of python installed you might have installed `discord` on a version of python which your IDE is not using right now. To change this on VS Code, do ctrl + shift + p, and then type in `Select Interpreter`. Change it to the version you downloaded it on (ideally the latest)

If you have PyCharm, refer [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-existing-interpreter)

If you have any other IDE, consider searching on Google.